# Proper removeView() usage

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

Can someone please explain where do put the removeView() in this case?

```
private void regListClickCallback() {

    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gamePlayList);
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    scorCh = li.inflate(R.layout.score_change_layout, null);

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long idInDB) {

            AlertDialog.Builder aDB = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            aDB.setView(scorCh);
            aDB.setCancelable(false).setMessage(i).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog aD = aDB.create();
            aD.show();
        }
    });

}
```

When I run the app I can click on one of the list items and get the dialog, but when I click the same item again or any other item, I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I have tried to put the following code both in onCreate and in this regListClickCallback.

```
 if(scorCh!=null)
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) scorCh.getParent();
        if(parent!=null)
            parent.removeView(scorCh);
    };
```

Comment: and what you expected? ... view has already parent: dialog ... inflate this view inside on click event ... also for your sanity do not store scorCh as class field ... make it final local variable inside on click ...

Comment: Try to replace `scorCh = li.inflate(R.layout.score_change_layout, null);` to `scorCh = li.inflate(R.layout.score_change_layout, parent, false);`

Comment: Why are you inflating a list and registering a click callback **inside** a click callback? Do you really intend to create a new list every time `regListClickCallback` is called?

Comment: @Selvin Oh, you're right. I thought regListClickCallback was a click callback.